# boost iostreams: output_filter works only once

Tags: c++, boost, filter, boost-iostreams

I am trying to use an [boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) [output filter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) to add a string to the beginning and the end of whatever I stream out.

My code below works, but only the first time; the second time, the output seems to get lost somewhere, the write method doesn't even seem to get called. I thought at first I'm sending something to the stream that triggers its fail bit, but the stream seems good.

The same problem occurs on mac and linux, with latest [boost release (1.48)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/) and [svn trunk](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/), with cout and a file sink as device.

Has anyone actually seen this work ? Is that a bug ? Or am I doing something wrong in my code ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/iostreams/concepts.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/operations.hpp>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::streamsize;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;

class add_string_output_filter
 : public boost::iostreams::multichar_output_filter
{
    public:

    template<typename Sink>
    streamsize write(Sink& sink, const char* s, streamsize n)
    {
        string out_string = string(s);

        // remove trailing '\0' to prevent line break
        if (out_string[out_string.size()-1] == '\0')
            out_string = out_string.substr(0, out_string.size()-1);

        string pre_string("prepended string - ");
        string app_string(" - appended string");

        stringstream sstrm;
        sstrm << pre_string << out_string << app_string << endl;

        // TODO: char* to string, back to char* ?!?
        return boost::iostreams::write(sink,
                                       sstrm.str().c_str(),
                                       sstrm.str().length());
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream out;

    out.push(add_string_output_filter());
    out.push(cout);

    // string #01 is printed,
    // string #02 gets lost
    out << "string #01" << endl;
    out << "string #02" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a lot of things wrong with your code, but I'm not sure
why the second string is not being output.  When I try the code, your
`add_string_output_filter::write` is only called once (with 
`"string #01\n"`); I would expect it to be called each time the buffer is
flushed (so a second time after the second `std::endl`).  But even if it
were called a second time, I don't think the output is what you expect
or want.  For prefixing and suffixing lines, you have to actually look
at the data, and process a `'\n'` character correctly.  This is much
simpler with a simple output filter:

```
class PrefixAndSuffixLineOutputFilter : public boost::iostreams::output_filter
{
    bool isAtStartOfLine;
public:
    PrefixAndSuffixLineOutputFilter() : isAtStartOfLine( true ) {}

    template <typename Sink>
    bool
    put( Sink& dest, char ch )
    {
        static std::string const prefix( "prepending string - " );
        static std::string const suffix( " - appended string" );

        bool retval = true;
        if ( isAtStartOfLine )
            retval = boost::iostreams::write( dest, prefix.data(), prefix.size() ) == prefix.size();
        if ( retval && ch == '\n' )
            retval = boost::iostreams::write( dest, suffix.data(), suffix.size() ) == suffix.size();
        if ( retval )
            retval = boost::iostreams::put( dest, ch );
        isAtStartOfLine = ch == '\n';
        return retval;
    }
};
```

In general, the `multichar_output_filter` is an optimization.  If you
read the tutorial, at the end, it says “Note that the
implementation of write is very similar to what you would get if you put
the implementation of shell_comments_output_filter::put inside a for
loop iterating from 0 to n.”  This is really the key: write the
simple `output_filter` first, and if the profiler shows that the
function calls are causing a performance problem, switch to the
`multichar_output_filter`.  (And note that you'd need the same state in
it, since you'll have to output the prefix and suffix correctly regardless of where
the `'\n'` occurs in multicharacter buffer.)

I might add that the `isAtStartOfLine` state is very frequence in output
filters.  (Note that you cannot simply output `prefix` after every
`'\n'`, since that will result in a dangling string `"prefix"` after the
final `'\n'`, and no `"prefix"` at the start of the first line.)  I had
a good example of this in my own code, which inserted a timestamp at the
beginning of each line, but Jonathan Turkanis didn't include this
particular example in his tutorial.